# Pass Javascript object as prop in React server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core, server-side-rendering, reactjs.net

I am using ReactJS.net to render react server side

**Below is the code in my cshtml file**

```
@Html.ReactRouter("RootComponent", new {services="service" }, containerId: "containerID")
```

Here i need to pass services to the child component. I have also declared the object in my entry point file

```
import service from '../../src/components/service.jsx';

global.service = service ;
```

Is there a way to access that object

Answer (score 0):

Should it be **=** instead of **:**?

```
@Html.ReactRouter("RootComponent", new {services = "service" }, containerId: "containerID")
```

The written above means that in your `RootComponent` you will be able to access `services` in it's `props`.
So, it will be something like

```js
class RootComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  // ...

  render () {
    const { services } = this.props;
    // ...
  }
}
```

or

```js
function RootComponent ({ services }) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: it was typing mistake i did edit my question, problem is while rendering it server side the "service" props gets undefined and HTML is not rendered on browser. "Service" is undefined  is the error that i get in console

Comment: At which point in the code you are getting that error? What is the place when you try to access `services`?

Comment: services is accessed in root component as this.props.services and there i get it is undefined

Comment: Oh. I think I understand. Do you first `import service ...` then `global.service = service` and then you want to pass it to RootComponent?

Comment: yes correct. the point is that variable is not accessible in cshtml ie server side and it gets undefined browser console